# Why are Faultstrings different?

Tags: web-services, exception, azure

I have a web service and I throw a soap exception. If I host it on Azure I got a different [faultstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soapfault.faultstring.aspx) , if I host on dev fabric I got a different fault string. Why are they different and how can I control them?

Comment: I'm guessing that one is blue, and the other is red. Is that right? If I'm wrong, then maybe you could post the two faults so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Development Web Server is different from the IIS 7.5 web servers that are used in staging and production, I'm guessing that this may cause your SOAP faultstring to differ in your scenario. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx